# Is there a way to use the same loop for 2 lists?

Tags: java

Is there a way to "combine" these loops, or a way to only write them once but still get each list to print independently?

```java
public static void printAnimals(String listType) {
    if (listType.equals("dog") {
        for (Dog obj: dogList) {
            System.out.println("elements"); // example output
        }
    }
    if (listType.equals("cat") {
        for (Cat obj: catList) {
            System.out.println("elements") // example output
        }
    }
```

In my actual code, there is a 3rd option "available" that prints a list of available dogs and available cats. So there, too, I have 2 identical loops that go through each list and prints only dogs or cats that are available. They're already written, so if it is the only way, it's the only way. I simply have a vague suspicion that there is probably a more efficient way.

```java
if (listType.equals("available") {
    for (Dog obj: dogList) {
        if (dog.getStatus().equals("unreserved") {
            System.out.println("unreserved dogs")
        }
    }
    
    for (Cat obj: catList) {
        if (cat.getStatus().equals ("unreserved") {
            System.out.println("unreserved cats")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your `Cat` and `Dog` types have some common superclass or implement a common interface? A [mcve] would help here. (It's worth reading the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) carefully by the way - see the edit I made to your post to format the code more readably, in particular using a triple backtick rather than a triple apostrophe. Use the preview to check that your post looks the way you want it to before submitting it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a single variable to be a reference for your list of animals and depending of kind of listype this variable is ponting to one list or another.

It's the most basic way to solve your issue.

```
public static void printAnimals(String listType) {
    var myList = listType.equals("dog") ? dogList : catList;
            
    for (Obj obj: myList) {
        System.out.println("elements"); // example output
    }
}
```

There is also another way that is a better solution:

```
public static void printDogs() {
    printAnimals(dogList);
}

public static void printCats() {
    printAnimals(catList);
}

private static void printAnimals(List animals) {
    for (Animal obj: animals) {
        System.out.println("elements"); // example output
    }
}
```

You must to ensure that Dogs and Cats extends a commnon Animal class.

Comment: It seems like these options would require just relocating the code somewhere else, correct?  (I'm not critiquing the answer, i'm just making sure I understand what I'm seeing)

Comment: The second answer is the proper way to work with OOP. Setting a common class like Animal to your 2 other animals, you are not realocating code but handling the common class instead of handling cats/dogs. The methods printDogs and printCats are just a way to show you how to call printAnimals

Answer (score 0):

By using the `OOP` principles, that here it is known as `Inheritance`, you can do something like this:

```
public class Animal {
        public void printAnimals(List<Animal> list) {
            System.out.println("do anything"); // sample output

        }
    }

    public class Dog extends Animal {

        @Override
        public void printAnimals(List<Animal> list) {
            System.out.println("print dogs"); // dogs output

        }
    }

    public class Cat extends Animal {

        @Override
        public void printAnimals(List<Animal> list) {
            System.out.println("print cats"); // cats output

        }
    }
```

Comment: And if I wanted to call the cat list from driver, it would be printAnimals(List<Cat> List); ?

Comment: @ktkricer exactly!!